# pagination error there is no records in page two

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

i searched about php pagination and i found a site who explains the codes very well, my question is about the codes, everytime i click "next" link, page 2 has to results. i dont understand why page 2 has no results.  here is the code:

```
 <?php 
 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); 

 mysql_select_db("kp_and_harang") or die(mysql_error()); 

 if (!(isset($pagenum))) 

 { 

 $pagenum = 1; 

 } 
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM students") or die(mysql_error()); 

 $rows = mysql_num_rows($data); 





 $page_rows = 4; 





 $last = ceil($rows/$page_rows); 




 if ($pagenum < 1) 

 { 

 $pagenum = 1; 

 } 

 elseif ($pagenum > $last) 

 { 

 $pagenum = $last; 

 } 





 $max = 'limit ' .($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows .',' .$page_rows; 

 $data_p = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM students $max") or die(mysql_error()); 



 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data_p )) 

 { 

 Print $info['surname']; 

 echo "<br>";

 } 

 echo "<p>";


 echo " --Page $pagenum of $last-- <p>";
 if ($pagenum == 1) 

 {

 } 

 else 

 {

 echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=1'> <<-First</a> ";

 echo " ";

 $previous = $pagenum-1;

 echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$previous'> <-Previous</a> ";

 } 


 echo " ---- ";



 if ($pagenum == $last) 

 {

 } 

 else {

 $next = $pagenum+1;

 echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$next'>Next -></a> ";

 echo " ";

 echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$last'>Last ->></a> ";

 } 

 ?>
```

Comment: Why don't you `echo` your SQL statement on each page? Then you should propably see if the calculation is wrong, when trying the SQL statement in phpMyAdmin. BTW: The (missing) indentation of your code makes it really hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, unless absolutely necessary it's not advisable to use `SELECT *` you should use specific fields. Right now you're making a full search on the same table twice. Select one field only if you want to count the rows only.

You should also use `PDO` functions instead of `mysql_*` which are *deprecated*.

Are you sure there should be a second page? How many records are there in `students` table?

To debug your code dump query results and check the `"SELECT * FROM students $max"` query.

Comment: actually i have 50 records in my students database and i want to paginate it with 10 records per page.

Comment: then make sure to follow my advice and dump the query and results you get from the DB.

Answer (score 0):

You put the page number in the url, but you never retrieve it from the url?

I changed this part:

```
if (!(isset($pagenum))) 
{ 
   $pagenum = 1; 
}
```

to this:

```
 if (!(isset($_GET['pagenum']))) 
 { 
    $pagenum = 1; 
 } else {
    $pagenum = $_GET['pagenum'];
 }
```

And it seems to work perfectly.

**EDIT**

To just get the total count of rows you don't have to fetch everything. You can just do the following:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM students") or die(mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_fetch_row($result);
```

Comment: great! but the  problem is it will retrive all the records in the database. i want to retrieve the records of whatever i choose in the combo box. thank you!

Comment: You can use count() in your sql statement to just get a count (number) of rows instead of having to retrieve all rows first. (Edited my answer)